# When does a closed walk not have a cycle?

Tags: graph-theory

Closed walk: sequence of vertices and edges where the first vertex is also the last
Cycle: closed walk where all vertices are different (except for first/last)

I can't think of an example where a closed walk is not a cycle because the cycle can just omit the part not needed.

For example in the graph bellow A,B,C,E,B,D,A is a closed walk and A,B,D,A is a cycle. Am I thinking of this wrong, does a cycle mean there is no repeating parts anywhere in the graph?

[image: example graph]

Comment: You have written " I can't think of an example where a closed walk **is not** a cycle because the cycle can just omit the part not needed. ". I think you didn't mean it. Rather I think you meant this -  " I can't think of an example where a closed walk **does not contain** a cycle because the cycle can just omit the part not needed. "

Answer (score 2):

Consider the walk $A \rightarrow D \rightarrow A$ in your graph above. This ends up at the node you started from, but does not contain a cycle. The definition of a cycle is a path that starts and ends at the same vertex without repeating any edges. Note that a cylce may have repeated vertices, but a *simple* cycle doesn't, so $A \rightarrow D \rightarrow B \rightarrow E \rightarrow C \rightarrow B \rightarrow A$ is a cycle but not a simple cycle due to the repetition of vertex $B$

Comment: So, are you saying that a closed path can have repeated vertices?

Comment: It must have by definition, as the start and end vertices are the same. Any other vertices may also repeat, for example $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow B \rightarrow A$ is a closed walk with vertices that repeat that aren't the start / end vertex

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. I thought closed path is you end where you started, but didn't know that vertices between them can repeat. Thank you for clarifying it.

Comment: Please check  [**the popular definition of walk, tail and path**](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Path_(graph_theory)&oldid=943257610#Walk,_trail,_path) and [**the popular definition of circuit and cycle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cycle_(graph_theory)&oldid=943599432#Circuit,_cycle).